# Using AS3 I want to do slow motion, fast forward, and rewind on audio

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I googled "as3 audio slow motion fast forward rewind" and found only this of relevance: [playing slow motion, fast forward , rewind in a video player in flash video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261681/playing-slow-motion-fast-forward-rewind-in-a-video-player-in-flash-video-play), which briefly talks about how to fast forward and rewind a video as well as two options for doing slow motion on video. I only need audio, though.

I think I might be able to do fast forward and rewind by stopping the SoundChannel and then playing the sound at a different position using addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ~), but I'm completely lost on how to apply the advice regarding slow motion.

Side note: I use Flash CS5.5 and all the sounds I want to operate on are already in the library - I'm not sure if that's at all relevant, but... uh... yeah...

SOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this look promising:
http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2009/pitch-mp3/

Comment: I would vote you up if I had the reputation to, thank you so very much!