# AS3 I'm trying to reproduce SampleDataEvent's data property on Sound objects that aren't loaded externally

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

Earlier today I asked a question here  [Using AS3 I want to do slow motion, fast forward, and rewind on audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737938/using-as3-i-want-to-do-slow-motion-fast-forward-and-rewind-on-audio) and received a link to some useful code here http://blog.andre-michelle.com/upload/mp3pitch/MP3Pitch.as.

I've been trying to use their code but I've run into a problem - their code assumes that the sound will be loaded externally, but my sound files are already imported in the library, so the SampleSoundEvent will never run!

I've been trying to get the code to do everything the handler would do, eliminating the need for the handler, but this code in the handler has been giving me problems: "var data: ByteArray = event.data;" where event is the SampleDataEvent.

I thought the equivalent might be `"var data: ByteArray; _mp3.extract(data, _mp3.length * 44.1);"` where `_mp3` is the Sound object. But when I test it by replacing the code inside the handler, I get this error: `"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference"`, which indicates that they are not equivalent.

I then tried to convert the sound file to ByteArray with `"var data: ByteArray = ByteArray(_mp3);` As expected, it couldn't be converted like that. I'm grasping at straws~

SOS

It's been about a week and I've just about given up on this (maybe it was not possible in the first place), but if anyone could share their knowledge, I'd be pretty happy, if only to be sure that it is not possible. :S

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/battalion-chiefs/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FexternalLibrary%2Fcom%2Fbattalion%2Faudio

Use this, it might help and it's decently documented.
It makes the use of audio similar to the use of BitmapData objects and Bitmaps.

Here's the documentation

http://code.google.com/p/battalion-chiefs/downloads/detail?name=FlashPointDocs.zip